# Can not open file with special charecters from Java when using Eclipse on MacOSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, utf-8

Hi friends of encoding problems,

let's assume we have a code like this:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class UTF8Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
            System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());

            File file = new File("Hello World ÄÖÜ.rtf");

            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this from Eclipse on Mac I get the following output:

```
UTF-8
UTF-8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: Hello World ÄÖÜ.rtf doesn't exist.
    at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:209)
    at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
    at UTF8Main.main(UTF8Main.java:16)
```

If I run it from the terminal I get the following output...

```
$java -cp ./bin UTF8Main main
UTF-8
UTF-8
```

...and the file opens in TextEdit.

Doing the same thing on Windows from Eclipse...

```
UTF-8
UTF-8
```

...and the file opens.

And from the Windows CMD...

```
>java -cp ./bin UTF8Main main
Cp1252
windows-1252
```

...and the file opens.

Does anybody know

1. How to get the thing working from the Eclipse on Mac?
2. Why the Windows Eclipse is printing UTF-8 to the console (optional just to understand whats going on)?

Comment: On your Mac, what was the projects encoding? Also, what was the run configuration console encoding? It sounds like one or both was not UTF-8

Comment: The project encoding is UTF-8, the runtime encoding was also UTF-8 (by setting -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8). But as playing around with these settings did not change anything, I tried the same on Windows and was astonished that it worked as expected.
As far as I understood, the project encoding aims to the encoding and compilation of my *.java files. The file.encoding property aims on how the compiled *.class files should be interpreted. Correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the Eclipse on OSX in Preferences->Java->Installed JREs I had Java 1.7.0_10 as default JRE where as the Mac Terminal and the Windows Eclipse used 1.7.0_40.

So updating all development environments to the latest 1.7.0_80 solved the problem for me.